# Does Allah create for man his wife from himself?

Tags: nikah, creation

This is vague to me. As said in several places that He created for you from yourselves mates.. Example:

> Surah 39. Az-Zumar, Ayah 6:
>
> He created you all from a single person, then from that person He created his mate. He also created for you eight head of cattle in pairs. He creates you in the wombs of your mothers in stages, one after another, in three layers of darkness. This is Allah, your Rabb. To Him belongs the sovereignty. There is no god but Him. How can you then turn away from Him?

Did he create once (at the beginning) or repeatedly doing so (for every person)? Can anybody please clarify it?

Jazakallah Khayer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no evidence for repeatedly do so in Qur'an. So It was once for the beginning.

There are Quranic verses which imply that Eve was created from the extra clay  Prophet Adam was created from.

The verses are as follows:

> **1-**  یا أَیُّهَا النَّاسُ اتَّقُوا رَبَّکُمُ الَّذی خَلَقَکُمْ مِنْ نَفْسٍ واحِدَةٍ وَ خَلَقَ مِنْها زَوْجَها
>
> O mankind, fear your Lord, who created you from one soul and created
>   from it its mate...(Surat An-Nisā',verse 1)
>
> **2-**  هُوَ الَّذی خَلَقَکُمْ مِنْ نَفْسٍ واحِدَةٍ وَ جَعَلَ مِنْها زَوْجَها لِیَسْکُنَ إِلَیْها
>
> It is He who created you from one soul and created from it its mate
>   that he might dwell in security with her...(Surat Al-'A`rāf,verse 189)
>
> **3-**  خَلَقَکُمْ مِنْ نَفْسٍ واحِدَةٍ ثُمَّ جَعَلَ مِنْها زَوْجَها
>
> He created you from one soul. Then He made from it its mate...(Surat
>   Az-Zumar,verse 6)

In addition in Surat An-Nisā',verse 1 Allah said:

> يا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ اتَّقُوا رَبَّکُمُ الَّذي خَلَقَکُمْ مِنْ نَفْسٍ
>   واحِدَةٍ وَ خَلَقَ مِنْها زَوْجَها وَ بَثَّ مِنْهُما رِجالاً
>   کَثيراً...
>
> O mankind, fear your Lord, who created you from one soul and created
>   from it its mate and dispersed from both of them many men and
>   women...(Surat An-Nisā',verse 1)

So as you see Allah dispersed from both Eve and Adam many men and women which naturally dispersed from them many men and women, too.

It shows that the women (wives) are from the first generation of human being which is Eve and Adam such other men are(Not to be from other men which themselves are from Eve and Adam).

So, It was just once for Eve and Adam.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Allah created everyone from one person in the beginning & this person is Adam...
And his wife (Havva or Eve) from the remaining mud of Adam...

Comment: Duplicate of an answer without adding or taking anything from it.